# php block parties do not open by js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

my problem is that the open page for example. 2.php through ajax file 1.php

but normally when you enter http: //localhost/2.php this page is normally open, and I would like to

I'm in 1.php and through hole ajax file 2.php it works all

when the hole in the address 2.php it is open the error.php page

or can you help me somehow? :)

myjs

```
<script>

    $(function () {

        $('#menu-list a').hover(function () {
            $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#FF803D"}, '1000');
        }, function () {

            $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#FFFB89"}, '1000');
        });


        $(".linkopen").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();


            var successdata;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: $(this).attr("href") + '#book',
                success: function (data) {
                    successdata = data;
                }

            });


            $('#text').fadeOut('1000', function () {

                $('#text').empty();
                $('#text').append(successdata);
            });
            $('#text').fadeIn('1000', function () {

            });

        });


    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want 2.php is only available if is an ajax request, and if you put it in the browser change the location to error.php?

http://www.paulund.co.uk/use-php-to-detect-an-ajax-request

here is an example to know if the request is an ajax (could be break)

if is not an ajax request you could use

```
header('Location: error_page.php');
```